# How to generate a video with python, matplotlib and opencv?

Tags: python, matplotlib, opencv

Here is what I have now.

The imported libraries:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
```

For instance(this part of code is from internet example), I draw a plot with a "text" on it.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6.5))
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.gca()
ax.text(0.0,0.0,"Test", fontsize=45)
ax.axis('off')
```

Then, I save it to, well, "1.png".

```
plt.savefig("1.png")
```

Finally, I create a video writer and write the png into the video.

```
size = (600,650)
fps = 2
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('I', '4', '2', '0')
video = cv2.VideoWriter("1.avi", fourcc, fps, size)
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
video.write(image)
video.release()
```

**Here is the question: I need to save the picture and then read it as the numpy array that opencv can read, is there any way that I can directly transform the fig object to the image object(numpy array)?**

Thank you guys very much!

Comment: I think this is doing what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603161/convert-an-image-shown-in-python-into-an-opencv-image

Comment: I have tried the method, I there are some bug at what is did on slicing. But yeah, that's what I wanna to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze step-by-step:

1. ```py
   size = (600,650)
   ```

Does the size of the image is `600, 650`?

If I were you, I would initialize as

```py
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
(height, width) = image.shape[:2]
size = (width, height)
```

or if you want the output as `(600, 650)`, then resize the image:

```py
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
image = cv2.resize(image, (600, 650))
```

2. ```py
   fps = 2
   ```

Why? you set frame-per-second to 2, why not 10?, 15? [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906361/how-do-i-use-the-fps-argument-in-cv2-videowriter/13948505)

3. ```py
   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('I', '4', '2', '0')
   ```

Why `I420`? You want to create `.avi` file, then set to `MJPG` [source](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/)

If I were you, I would initialize as:

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
```

4. ```py
   video = cv2.VideoWriter("1.avi", fourcc, fps, size)
   ```

What type of images are you working with? color, gray?. You need to initialize as a parameter in the `VideoWriter`

For color image:

```py
video = cv2.VideoWriter("1.avi", fourcc, fps, size, isColor=True)
```

For gray images:

```py
video = cv2.VideoWriter("1.avi", fourcc, fps, size, isColor=False)
```

An example code:

---

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("1.png")
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
size = (w, h)
fps = 20
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
video = cv2.VideoWriter("1.avi", fourcc, fps, size, isColor=True)
video.write(img)
video.release()
```

Also know that `cv2.imread` reads the image in `BGR` fashion. If you want your images as `RGB` you need to convert it like:

```py
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: You addressed everything except the question asked, which was how to go from figure to video frame without a PNG file in-between.

Comment: "frame without a PNG file in-between" then how do you show a frame?

Comment: You get an image of the matplotlib figure in-memory, uncompressed.  For example with `figure.canvas.buffer_rgba()`.  The video encoder wants uncompressed input data anyway.  If you save to a PNG first, you're wasting time on PNG compression, disk I/O, and decompression.